# I have an embedding $\iota$ between two Hilbert spaces and want to know if $\iota\iota^\ast$ is something simple like an orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, stochastic-analysis, isometry

I'm reading *[A Concise Course on Stochastic Partial Differential Equations](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540707806?token=prtst0416p)*. In [Proposition 2.5.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q-JDooJbjCAC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22+%22proposition+2.5.2%22&source=bl&ots=QOm7F0ZT3K&sig=1W5EyAN_DS-mcdKiyixmCzSObBU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVwobIyZXNAhVBXCwKHc26DIEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22%20%22proposition%202.5.2%22&f=false) the authors define the notion of a *cylindrical $Q$-Wiener process* $W$. It turns out that $W$ is just a *[$Q_1$-Wiener process](https://books.google.de/books?id=2QS0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22+%22Definition+2.1.9%22&source=bl&ots=TCuhKdG-fI&sig=Ndcq6NNIu-Cq7XDWpPp7coupZWk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_wqn25ZrNAhXEESwKHYtGCPoQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22%20%22Definition%202.1.9%22&f=false)* on a "larger" Hilbert space. I've got the feeling that $Q_1$ is actually a really "simple" operator (like the identity or some kind of projection), especially in the popular case where $Q$ is the identity, but I got problems to figure that out.

Let me introduce the necessary objects: Let$^1$

- $U$ and $V$ be real Hilbert spaces
- $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and symmetric
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{U_0}:=\langle Q^{-1/2}u,Q^{-1/2}v\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in U_0$$
- $\iota\in\operatorname{HS}(U_0,V)$ be an embedding
- $C:=\iota\iota^\ast$
- $V_0:=C^{1/2}V$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{V_0}:=\langle C^{-1/2}u,C^{-1/2}v\rangle_V\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in V_0$$

In [Proposition 2.5.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q-JDooJbjCAC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22+%22proposition+2.5.2%22&source=bl&ots=QOm7F0ZT3K&sig=1W5EyAN_DS-mcdKiyixmCzSObBU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVwobIyZXNAhVBXCwKHc26DIEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22%20%22proposition%202.5.2%22&f=false) the authors show that $V_0=\iota U_0$ and that $\iota$ is an isometry between $U_0$ and $V_0$.

> If we treat $\iota$ as being an element of $\mathfrak L(U_0,V_0)$, it's easy to see that $\iota$ is [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator) and hence $$C=\text{id}_{V_0}\;.$$ However, in the context of the book, I need to treat $\iota$ as an element of $\mathfrak L(U_0,V)$ (in [Proposition 2.5.2](https://books.google.de/books?id=Q-JDooJbjCAC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22+%22proposition+2.5.2%22&source=bl&ots=QOm7F0ZT3K&sig=1W5EyAN_DS-mcdKiyixmCzSObBU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVwobIyZXNAhVBXCwKHc26DIEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22r%C3%B6ckner%22%20%22proposition%202.5.2%22&f=false) the authors show that $\iota$ is nonnegative and symmetric with finite [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Definition)). I think that even in that case $C$ is something really "simple", but I don't know what I need to do to reveal that.

---

$^1$ Let $\mathfrak L(A,B)$ and $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denote the space of bounded, linear operators and [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) from $A$ to $B$, respectively, and $\mathfrak L(A):=\mathfrak L(A,A)$.