# How can we compute the adjoint of the inclusion between two Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let

- $\mathbb K\in\left\{\mathbb C,\mathbb R\right\}$
- $(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U)$ and $(V,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V)$ be $\mathbb K$-Hilbert spaces such that $U\subseteq V$ and that the inclusion $\iota:(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U)\to(V,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V)$ is [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator)
- $C:=\iota^\ast$ denote the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces) of $\iota$ and $$\langle u,v\rangle_0:=\langle C^{-\frac 12}u,C^{-\frac 12}v\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in U$$

We can show that $$U=C^{\frac 12}V\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_0=\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U\;.$$

> How can we compute what the adjoint $C$ of $\iota$ actually is?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the adjoint of $\iota$? Adjoints are defined for endomorphisms of a Hilbert space, but $\iota$ is between two different Hilbert spaces. Because one is contained in the other (presumably as a vector subspace, though you didn't indicate that), you could argue that it qualifies, but you have different inner products, so it is unclear which inner product should play which role in the definition of the adjoint.

Comment: @PaulSinclair If $T$ is a bounded, linear operator between $H_1$ and $H_2$ then the adjoint $T^\ast$ of $T$ is a bounded, linear operator between $H_2$ and $H_1$ with $$\langle Tu,v\rangle_{H_2}=\langle u,T^\ast v\rangle_{H_1}\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in H_1\text{ and }v\in H_2\;.$$ $\iota$ is considered as a Hilbert-Schmidt operator between $U$ and $V$, where both Hilbert spaces are equipped with their corresponding inner product $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U$ and $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V$, respectively.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Honestly, I don't know whether or not $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_0$ as an additional inner product on $U$ is important here. Please notice that I've asked an [additional question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819556/i-have-an-embedding-iota-between-two-hilbert-spaces-and-want-to-know-if-iot) for a more general case. Maybe this helps you to understand the motivation, but I think it's not important here.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: adjoints are regularly defined for any map between vector spaces. If $T:X\to Y$, then you define $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$ by $$ (T^*g)(x)=g(Tx).$$

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\iota$ is HS means that if $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$, then 
$$\tag{1}
\sum_n\langle e_n,e_n\rangle_V=\sum_n\|\iota(e_n)\|_V^2<\infty.
$$

After identifying $U$ and $V$ with their respective duals, we have $C:V\to U$ given by 
$$\tag{2}
\langle Cv,u\rangle_U=\langle v,\iota (u)\rangle_V=\langle v,u\rangle_V.
$$
In particular, if $\{f_m\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then
$$
\langle Cf_m,e_n\rangle_U=\langle f_m,e_n\rangle_V.
$$
Since each $e_n\in V$, we can write $e_n=\sum_m\langle e_n,f_m\rangle_V\,f_m$. Then 
$$
Cf_m=\sum_n\langle Cf_m,e_n\rangle_U\,e_n=\sum_n\langle f_m,e_n\rangle_V\,e_n,
$$
and it follows by continuity that
$$\tag{3}
Cv=\sum_n\langle v,e_n\rangle_V\,e_n.
$$
Note that the sum converges because the sequence $(\langle v,e_n\rangle_V)$ is in $\ell^2$, by Cauchy-Schwarz and $(1)$.

When we think of $C$ as a map $V\to V$ (since $U\subset V$), it is immediate from $(3)$ that $C$ is positive:
$$
\langle Cv,v\rangle_V=\sum_n\langle v,e_n\rangle_V\,\langle e_n,v\rangle_V=\sum_n|\langle v,e_n\rangle_V|^2\geq0.
$$So it makes sense to talk about $C^{1/2}$. Now, if the inclusion $U\subset V$ is proper and $U$ is $V$-closed, then if $v\in V\cap U^\perp$ (orthogonal taken in $V$), then by $(2)$ we have 
$$
\langle Cv,u\rangle_U=\langle v,u\rangle_V=0
$$
for all $u\in U$, so $Cv=0$. So, in this case $C$ is not invertible and so it makes no sense to talk about $C^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I denote by $C^{-1}$ the pseudo inverse of $C$, i.e. $$C^{-1}:=\left(\left.C\right|_{\ker(C)^\perp}\right)^{-1}\;.$$

Comment: 1. If $v\in U$, then $(3)$ is similar to the basis expansion of $v$ in $U$. The only disturbing thing is that it involves $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V$ instead of $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U$. However, I think it's the most concrete representation of $C$ we can obtain, right? 2. From $(3)$, can we find a representation of $C^{1/2}$? I've asked for that in a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820877/how-can-we-compute-the-square-root-of-an-operator-of-the-form-cv-sum-n-in-mat).

Comment: Looks like that to me. As you say, it is disturbing that $\{e_n\}$ is not orthogonal on $\langle\cdot,\cdot,\rangle_V$. And without an explicit relation between the two inner products, It is not immediate to me how to find $C^{1/2}$. Note that condition $(1)$ implies that $e_n\to0$ (in norm) in $V$; so $C$ is compact when seen $C:V\to V$ (and not compact when seen $C:V\to U$).

Comment: The reason for this question is [another question of me](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241664/relationship-between-the-it%c5%8d-formula-for-a-q-wiener-process-and-the-it%c5%8d-formula). You need to know nothing about probability theory or PDEs. It's "pure" functional analysis. Maybe you know something which helps. Thanks for your efforts in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the expression for the adjoint of the inclusion I: U-> V without having a relation between norms of U and V.
Try with a specific example, e.g. inclusion of L^2 into H^(-1). In that case you should easily get the explicit expression for I^*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).