# How can we compute the square root of an operator of the form $Cv=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\langle v,e_n\rangle_Ve_n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Let

- $\mathbb K\in\left\{\mathbb C,\mathbb R\right\}$
- $U$ and $V$ be $\mathbb K$-Hilbert spaces such that $U\subseteq V$ and that the inclusion $\iota$ is [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator)
- $C:=\iota^\ast$ denote the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint#Definition_for_bounded_operators_between_Hilbert_spaces) of $\iota$
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$

[We can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820613/47771) that $$Cv=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\langle v,e_n\rangle_Ve_n\;\;\;\text{for all }v\in V\;.$$ How can we compute the square root $C^{1/2}$ of $C$? Note that $C^{1/2}$ exists and is uniquely determined, since $C$ is a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $V$.

Please note that I'm not interested in the case where $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U$ is the restriction of $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V$ to $U\times U$.

Answer (score 1):

This operator is the orthogonal projection onto $U$, it holds $C^2=C$:
First we find that
$$
\langle Cv,e_n\rangle = \langle v,e_n\rangle,
$$ 
since $(e_n)$ is orthonormal. This implies
$$
C^2v = \sum_n \langle Cv,e_n\rangle Ce_n =  \sum_n \langle v,e_n\rangle e_n =Cv.
$$
Hence, $C^2 = C$, which implies $C^{1/2}=C$.

Edit: I assumed that the scalar product on $U$ is the scalar product of $V$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the assumption that $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U$ is the restriction of $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V$ to $U\times U$ is way to restrictive for my purposes. The applications I'm interested in are (for example) $U=H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $V=L^2(\Omega)$.